# Why my python program of opening various applications (by using os module) not opening any application?

Tags: python

I have created the following code in python by using the 'os' module, with the purpose of opening particular application. But every time it runs, it doesn't give any output.

```
import os

def task_manager():
    task_query = "open vlc"

    # notepad logistics
    if "notepad" or "note pad" in task_query:
        # >> open notepad operations
        if "open notepad" in task_query:
            notepad_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"
            os.startfile(notepad_path)

    # vlc logistics
    elif "vlc media player" or "vlc" in task_query:
        # >> open vlc operations
        if "open vlc media player" or "open vlc" in task_query:
            vlc_path = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"
            os.startfile(vlc_path)

    # command prompt logistics
    elif "command prompt" or "cmd" in task_query:
        # >> open command prompt operations
        if "open command prompt" or "open cmd" in task_query:
            cmd_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            os.startfile(cmd_path)

    else:
        print("No application")

task_manager()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rare python properties... if the str is "**open notepad**" the first **if** accepts it since "**notepad**" is inside "**open notepad**" but then it asks us if "open notepad" is in "**open notepad**" and you says it is false. So either you set **task_query = "open notepad "** (that is, with a space) or you open a second **or** to the second if:

```
if "open notepad" in task_query or "open notepad" == task_query:
```

The whole code would be:

```
import os

def task_manager():
    task_query = "open vlc"

    # notepad logistics
    if "notepad" or "note pad" in task_query:
        # >> open notepad operations
        if "open notepad" in task_query or "open notepad" == task_query:
            notepad_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"
            os.startfile(notepad_path)

    # vlc logistics
    elif "vlc media player" or "vlc" in task_query:
        # >> open vlc operations
        if "open vlc media player" or "open vlc" in task_query or "open vlc" == task_query:
            vlc_path = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"
            os.startfile(vlc_path)

    # command prompt logistics
    elif "command prompt" or "cmd" in task_query:
        # >> open command prompt operations
        if "open command prompt" or "open cmd" in task_query or "open cmd" == task_query:
            cmd_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            os.startfile(cmd_path)

    else:
        print("No application")

task_manager()
```

Comment: This suffers still from the same basic problem: The misunderstanding of how `or` works.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are not doing what you intended.

```
if "a" or "b" in "cd":
    print("Inside")
# > Inside
```

That is because it is doing in fact three test comparisons, which are:

```
bool("a")
# > True
"b" in "cd"
# False
True or False
# True
```

You probably want to do:

```
elif "vlc media player" in task_query or "vlc" in task_query:
```

Which is, more elegantly put:

```
elif any(x in task_query for x in ("vlc media player", "vlc")):
```

#### About that last particular test

If "vlc media player" is inside a string, then a part of it is necessarly in that string also. `elif "vlc" in task_query` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. But there are better ways to write this code as mentioned in the comments.

```
import os

def task_manager():
    task_query = "open vlc"

    # notepad logistics
    if ("notepad" in task_query or "note pad" in task_query):
        # >> open notepad operations
        if ("open notepad" in task_query):
            notepad_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"
            os.startfile(notepad_path)

    # vlc logistics
    elif ("vlc media player" in task_query or "vlc" in task_query):
        # >> open vlc operations
        if ("open vlc media player" in task_query or "open vlc" in task_query):
            vlc_path = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe"
            os.startfile(vlc_path)

    # command prompt logistics
    elif ("command prompt" in task_query or "cmd" in task_query):
        # >> open command prompt operations
        if ("open command prompt" in task_query or "open cmd" in task_query):
            cmd_path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            os.startfile(cmd_path)

    else:
        print("No application")

task_manager()
```